# How to uninstall Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, uninstallation, oomph, eclipse-installer

I want to uninstall Eclipse version Mars 2, but it doesn't appear in the "Programs and Features" area of the Windows Control Panel. The installer has installed start menu shortcuts and other artifacts, so it's not just a matter of deleting the installation folder.

Comment: Which installer did you use? I think last time I installed eclipse it didn't add any start menu entries

Comment: @Kapep I think it's the eclipseinstaller (by Oomph) https://puu.sh/AF5F5/455cb8714e.png

Comment: @Halvra Ok, it seems the option to add shortcuts only exists in the simple mode, not in advanced mode

Comment: Right click the shortcut and select Properties then Target and it might give an indication of where it is stored on your system (Windows), and perhaps there's an uninstall exe or similar in that location.

Answer (score 133, accepted):

There is no automated uninstaller.

You have to remove Eclipse manually by deleting some directories and files.

*Note: I use Unix style paths in this answer but the locations should be the same on Windows or Unix systems, so `~` refers to the user home directory even on Windows.*

### Why is there no uninstaller?

According to this [discussion about uninstalling Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1079348/), the reasoning for not providing an uninstaller is that the Eclipse installer is supposed to just automate a few tasks that in the past had to be done manually (like downloading and extracting Eclipse and adding shortcuts), so they also can be undone manually. On Windows there is no entry in "Programs and Features" because the installer does not register installations in the system registry.

### How to to locate Eclipse installations

The default installation path is in `~/eclipse/`.

The Eclipse installer also keeps track of installations. Launch the installer and then open the "Bundle Pool" dialog (in simple mode it's in the menu - in advanced mode it's a small button next to the bundle pool drop down) and click on "Analyze Agent". You'll see list of *profiles*. Double click on a profile to see the path of the installation.

You could also search for files that contain "eclipse" in their name with any file search tool to locate installation folders. But be aware that Eclipse is a platform that other software can build upon, so there might be folders of Eclipse-based applications that look very much like Eclipse IDE installations but are actually software you might want to keep.

### How to quickly uninstall Eclipse

If you have installed Eclipse manually without the Eclipse installer, just delete the Eclipse directory and be done with it.

If you have installed Eclipse with the Eclipse installer, then delete the Eclipse directory and any desktop and start menu shortcuts. Then launch the Eclipse installer and open the "Bundle Pool" dialog and click on "Cleanup Agent" to remove unused bundles. This won't affect other Eclipse installations if you have any.

In my opinion this is generally enough and I would stop here

### How to completely uninstall Eclipse

If you really want to remove Eclipse without leaving any traces, you have to manually delete

- all desktop and start menu shortcuts
- all installation directories (e.g. `~/eclipse/photon/`)
- the p2 bundle pool (which is often shared with other eclipse installations)

The installer has a "Bundle Pools" menu entry which lists the locations of all bundle pools. If you have other Eclipse installations on your system you can use the "Cleanup Agent" to remove unused bundles. If you don't have any other Eclipse installations you can delete the whole bundle pool directory instead (by default `~/p2/`).

If you want to completely remove the *Eclipse installer* too, delete the installer's executable and the `~/.eclipse/` directory.

Depending on what kind of work you did with Eclipse, there can be more directories that you may want to delete. If you used Maven, then `~/.m2/` contains the Maven cache and settings (shared with Maven CLI and other IDEs). If you develop Eclipse plugins, then there might be JUnit workspaces from test runs, next to you Eclipse workspace. Likewise other build tools and development environments used in Eclipse could have created similar directories.

### How to delete all projects

If you want to delete your projects and workspace metadata, you have to delete your workspace(s). The default workspace location is ´~/workspace/´. You can also [search for the `.metadata` directory to get all Eclipse workspaces on your machine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54948948/897024).

If you are working with Git projects, these are generally not saved in the workspace but in the `~/git/` directory.

### Addendum: Windows Registry

Even though Eclipse isn't "installed" like a regular Windows application, there are still a few entries that get written to the system registry. If you search the Registry for "eclipse" you'll likely find  some entries for URL handlers named `eclipse+command`, `eclipse+mpc` or `eclipse+installer`. They are used e.g. for letting you install Eclipse plugins from the browser.

On my system I see a few other entries which I believe are created by Windows itself and not by Eclipse (e.g. entries in the list of recently used executables). Whether you want to delete those entries is up to you. Personally I wouldn't, but on the other hand it probably won't break anything if you do. Just be aware that registry "cleaning" is a controversial topic.

Comment: I am not sure this answer includes all locations though.  You mensioned p2 pool, I guess you are referring to the C:\Users\user-name\p2 directory uncer windows?  In addition, I see .eclipseextension, plugins, features directories which all have some *eclipse* reletad files

Comment: @pixel yes I mean that .p2 directory. There are probably a lot more locations, depending on how the IDE is configured. I have based the answer mostly on a standard installation of Eclipse for Java/Plugin development. As far as I understand the ".eclipseextension" file is used to run extensions from different locations which can be shared between Eclipse instances. I don't know much about that or how it is configured, if you have more information about it feel free to add it.

Comment: Is this answer a joke ? My eclipse kept getting stuck so i went and tried uninstalling, and after reading `At least eclipse does not write to system registry` i cringe, especially after seeing this: https://snipboard.io/z2WsEe.jpg

Comment: @Lorenzo Well "The installer just automates what you'd otherwise do manually. It does
not register anything in your system registry" is what Eclipse developers said about the topic a few years ago. This answer is not a joke but I actually hope that the complexity of uninstalling everything manually shows how out of touch their statement has become. Good to know that it actually *does* write something to the registry, maybe that can be used as argument to convince them that an automated uninstaller is needed eventually. I'll include information about the registry in the answer later.

Comment: I'm sorry, my IDE wasn't working and would get stuck during gradle build forever (2h+) so I apologize for the way i talked about the answer; i was quite frustrated. 
Overall, i never trust uninstallers and what companies say; that's why i use RevoUninstaller to remove programs; that's also how i found these registry entries and know not to trust uninstallers or companies. I recommend to use this because it avoids you having to manually search and remove entries by hand and it does a pretty good job in finding a lot of entries (based on scan mode there might be falsepositives so always verify)

Comment: It's okay, I know how frustrating something like that can be. In most cases Eclipse instances don't affect each other (unless there is some issue with the shared bundle pool) so I usually just install a fresh instance when one breaks and leave the old one be. I recently deleted about 30 Eclipse installations at once during a cleanup. I know most uninstallers leave some traces but Eclipse really makes you jump through hoops by not providing even a basic one.

Comment: Yes, I think it's important to note that Eclipse *does* put entries into the registry - I see all the same ones as Lorenzo, still in version 2021-03, and still there is no uninstaller (and there are multiple folders to clean up as well, as you said @kapex).  This seems like an oversight, or careless behaviour tbh.

Comment: Installed Eclipse for Java and Web developer, I installed it all to C:\Users\Myname\eclipse folder and set workspace to C:\Users\Myname\eclipse-workspace. After trying out a few Spring framework projects, there are just so many things did not work following many different instructions. I decided to uninstall it, first big thing is it does write to my windows 10 registry all over the place, so just merely saying it doesn't write to registry is a big lie! To be honest, in this day and age, trying to uninstall a program like I am doing a research project is a disgrace. Anyway, Eclipse is free.

Comment: @ForComment >"saying it doesn't write to registry is a big lie" I was just paraphrasing the developers from the linked forum thread. It probably was true at the time they said that years ago. Or maybe they were just nitpicking and meant that the _installer_ doesn't write to the registry, even though Eclipse may does so _after_ it has been installed. Do you have any example registry entries that aren't covered in the last paragraph? I still have hopes that documenting the ridiculous manual uninstall process here can be used to convince the devs to create an uninstaller.

Comment: @kapex Come to think of it, I should have kept a log of what I deleted form registry by searching for 'Eclipse'. Anyway, I might try it on another machine again, will do that. But at the moment, I think I am going to use IntelliJ.

Answer (score 3):

The steps are very simple and it'll take just few mins.
1.Go to your  C drive and in that go to the 'USER' section.
2.Under 'USER' section go to your 'name(e.g-'user1') and then find ".eclipse" folder and
delete that folder
3.Along with that folder also delete "eclipse" folder and you can find that you're
work has been done completely.

Answer (score 2):

Right click on eclipse icon and click on open file location then delete the eclipse folder from drive(Save backup of your eclipse workspace if you want). Also delete eclipse icon. Thats it..

Answer (score 1):

just search in widows bar for **eclipse.ini"* ,
and delete all folders in parent location

Answer (score 0):

Look for an installation subdirectory, likely named eclipse. Under that 
subdirectory, if you see files like eclipse.ini, icon.xpm and 
subdirectories like plugins and dropins, remove the subdirectory parent 
(the one named eclipse).

That will remove your installation except for anything you've set up 
yourself (like workspaces, projects, etc.).

Hope this helps.