# Does Eclipse installer make entries in Windows registry?

Tags: java, eclipse

From the Eclipse download site one can download the installer

File: eclipse-inst-win64.exe

or download ZIP files.

My question is, on Windows systems, does the installer make any entries in Registry?

Comment: No. It does not modify the registry.

Comment: All other answers are wrong. It does create new entries in the registry. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50855742

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse does not use the Windows registry. It uses different approaches (mechanisms) to persist configuration related information.

You can use command line options to gain some level of control when you are unhappy about the defaults that eclipse is using. See http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/running_eclipse.htm for example. Doing so can be helpful when installing different versions of eclipse on the same machine.

Comment: Can the installer be used to keep multiple versions of Eclipse on the same machine?

Comment: Sorry but this is wrong. Search "eclipse" in the windows registry and you will find entries that were created by the installer. Ex : Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\eclipse+installer

Comment: I think we are both right ... the question asked about the installer, I was talking about eclipse itself ;-) ... but then: having the installer write to the registry itself doesn't change that eclipse itself puts his configuration into files in specific folders. Or at least did that 3 years ago.

Answer (score -1):

no, eclipse does not changes registry in windows.

Comment: Thanks for contributing.  Unfortunately, your Answer does not say anything that has not already been said (with more detail ... and references) by the earlier question.  Answers like this don't help anyone, and are discouraged.