# I couldn't uninstall Eclipse IDE, so I deleted all Eclipse related files from my PC. Now I can't re-install it. I keep getting this weird error

Tags: eclipse, ide, oomph

I could not uninstall Eclipse IDE, so I deleted all Eclipse related files from my PC. Now I cannot re-install the program anymore. I keep getting this weird error. I have no idea what is going on.

https://pastebin.com/ndRendpX

```
[2021-11-18 20:37:26] Executing bootstrap tasks
[2021-11-18 20:37:26] OpenJDK Runtime Environment 16.0.2+7-67
[2021-11-18 20:37:26] Product org.eclipse.products.epp.package.cpp.2021-09
[2021-11-18 20:37:26] Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup 1.21.0.v20210808-1248, build=5169, branch=4f2d83d895798b31dc987dc9c07da7c94b536f1d
[2021-11-18 20:37:26] Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup.core 1.21.0.v20210828-0732, build=5169, branch=4f2d83d895798b31dc987dc9c07da7c94b536f1d
[2021-11-18 20:37:26] Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2 1.17.0.v20210601-0619, build=5169, branch=4f2d83d895798b31dc987dc9c07da7c94b536f1d
[2021-11-18 20:37:26] Performing P2 Director (Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers (2021-09))
[2021-11-18 20:37:26] Offline = false
[2021-11-18 20:37:26] Mirrors = true
[2021-11-18 20:37:26] Resolving 34 requirements from 3 repositoriesto C:\Users\Arjan\eclipse\cpp-2021-09\eclipse
[2021-11-18 20:37:26] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:epp.package.cpp [4.21.0,5.0.0) (filter=(|(&(osgi.arch=aarch64)(osgi.os=linux)(osgi.ws=gtk))(&(osgi.arch=x86_64)(osgi.os=linux)(osgi.ws=gtk))(&(osgi.arch=x86_64)(osgi.os=macosx)(osgi.ws=cocoa))(&(osgi.arch=x86_64)(osgi.os=win32)(osgi.ws=win32))))
[2021-11-18 20:37:26] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [4.21.0,5.0.0)
[2021-11-18 20:37:26] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group [4.21.0,5.0.0)
[2021-11-18 20:37:26] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.cdt.autotools.feature.group
[2021-11-18 20:37:26] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.cdt.build.crossgcc.feature.group
[2021-11-18 20:37:26] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.cdt.cmake.feature.group
[2021-11-18 20:37:26] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.cdt.debug.gdbjtag.feature.group
[2021-11-18 20:37:26] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.cdt.debug.standalone.feature.group
[2021-11-18 20:37:26] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.cdt.debug.ui.memory.feature.group
[2021-11-18 20:37:26] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.cdt.docker.launcher.feature.group
[2021-11-18 20:37:26] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.cdt.feature.group
[2021-11-18 20:37:26] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.cdt.launch.remote.feature.group
[2021-11-18 20:37:26] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.cdt.launch.serial.feature.feature.group
[2021-11-18 20:37:26] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.cdt.meson.feature.group
[2021-11-18 20:37:26] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.cdt.testsrunner.feature.feature.group
[2021-11-18 20:37:26] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.egit.feature.group
[2021-11-18 20:37:26] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.epp.mpc.feature.group
[2021-11-18 20:37:26] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.launchbar.feature.group
[2021-11-18 20:37:26] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.launchbar.remote.feature.group
[2021-11-18 20:37:26] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.linuxtools.cdt.libhover.devhelp.feature.feature.group
[2021-11-18 20:37:26] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.linuxtools.cdt.libhover.feature.feature.group
[2021-11-18 20:37:26] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.linuxtools.changelog.c.feature.group
[2021-11-18 20:37:26] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.linuxtools.gcov.feature.group
[2021-11-18 20:37:26] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.linuxtools.gprof.feature.feature.group
[2021-11-18 20:37:26] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.linuxtools.rpm.feature.group
[2021-11-18 20:37:26] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.linuxtools.valgrind.feature.group
[2021-11-18 20:37:26] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext_feature.feature.group
[2021-11-18 20:37:26] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.tm.terminal.connector.cdtserial.feature.feature.group
[2021-11-18 20:37:26] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.tm.terminal.feature.feature.group
[2021-11-18 20:37:26] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.tracecompass.gdbtrace.feature.group
[2021-11-18 20:37:26] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.tracecompass.lttng2.control.feature.group
[2021-11-18 20:37:26] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.tracecompass.lttng2.kernel.feature.group
[2021-11-18 20:37:26] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.tracecompass.lttng2.ust.feature.group
[2021-11-18 20:37:26] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.oomph.setup.feature.group
[2021-11-18 20:37:26] Repository https://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/2021-09/202109101200
[2021-11-18 20:37:26] Repository https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2021-09/202109151000
[2021-11-18 20:37:26] Repository http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
[2021-11-18 20:37:30] Calculating requirements and dependencies.
[2021-11-18 20:37:31] Computing prerequisite plan
[2021-11-18 20:37:32] Fetching artifacts.jar from https://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/2021-09/202109101200/ (2.11kB)
[2021-11-18 20:37:34] Fetching compositeArtifacts.jar from http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest/ (441B)
[2021-11-18 20:37:35] Fetching artifacts.xml.xz from http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/drops/milestone/S20211116-084220-1.23.0-M3/ (24.56kB)
[2021-11-18 20:37:35] Fetching artifacts.xml.xz from https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2021-09/202109151000/ (573.75kB)
[2021-11-18 20:37:36] Collecting 4 artifacts from https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2021-09/202109151000
[2021-11-18 20:37:37] Downloading org.eclipse.cdt_root
[2021-11-18 20:37:37] Downloading org.eclipse.rcp_root
[2021-11-18 20:37:37] Downloading org.eclipse.platform_root
[2021-11-18 20:37:37] Downloading org.eclipse.platform.ide.executable.win32.win32.x86_64
[2021-11-18 20:37:37] Fetching org.eclipse.platform_root_4.21.0.v20210906-0842 from https://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/software/eclipse/releases/2021-09/202109151000/binary/ (196B)
[2021-11-18 20:37:37] Fetching org.eclipse.platform.ide.executable.win32.win32.x86_64_4.21.0.I20210906-0500 from https://rhlx01.hs-esslingen.de/pub/Mirrors/eclipse/releases/2021-09/202109151000/binary/ (266.27kB)
[2021-11-18 20:37:37] Fetching org.eclipse.rcp_root_4.21.0.v20210906-0842 from https://ftp.acc.umu.se/mirror/eclipse.org/releases/2021-09/202109151000/binary/ (24.93kB)
[2021-11-18 20:37:37] Fetching org.eclipse.cdt_root_10.4.0.202109080104 from https://eclipse.mirror.garr.it/releases/2021-09/202109151000/binary/ (3.25kB)
[2021-11-18 20:37:37] Mirrored 1 artifacts from https://rhlx01.hs-esslingen.de/pub/Mirrors/eclipse/releases/2021-09/202109151000/ at 1,286kb/s
[2021-11-18 20:37:37] Mirrored 1 artifacts from https://ftp.acc.umu.se/mirror/eclipse.org/releases/2021-09/202109151000/ at 124kb/s
[2021-11-18 20:37:37] Mirrored 1 artifacts from https://eclipse.mirror.garr.it/releases/2021-09/202109151000/ at 8kb/s
[2021-11-18 20:37:37] Mirrored 1 artifacts from https://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/software/eclipse/releases/2021-09/202109151000/ at 2kb/s
[2021-11-18 20:37:37] Collected 4 artifacts for https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2021-09/202109151000 in 0.973s
[2021-11-18 20:37:37] Collecting 1 artifacts from https://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/2021-09/202109101200
[2021-11-18 20:37:37] Downloading epp.package.cpp.executable.win32.win32.x86_64
[2021-11-18 20:37:38] Fetching epp.package.cpp.executable.win32.win32.x86_64_4.21.0.20210910-1410 from https://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/2021-09/202109101200/binary/ (266.27kB)
[2021-11-18 20:37:38] Mirrored 1 artifacts from https://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/2021-09/202109101200/ at 276kb/s
[2021-11-18 20:37:38] Collected 1 artifacts for https://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/2021-09/202109101200 in 1.005s
[2021-11-18 20:37:38] An error was detected while performing the engine operation and the changes are being rolled back. See the log for details.
[2021-11-18 20:37:38] ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine code=4 An error occurred during the org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust phase.
  at org.eclipse.oomph.util.OomphPlugin.coreException(OomphPlugin.java:291)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl$3.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:553)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:345)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2.impl.P2TaskImpl.perform(P2TaskImpl.java:904)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.doPerformNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3851)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3779)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performTriggeredSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3760)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.perform(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3638)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.installPerform(SimpleVariablePage.java:1343)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.access$33(SimpleVariablePage.java:1211)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage$20.run(SimpleVariablePage.java:1156)
  ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine code=0 session context was:(profile=C__Users_Arjan_eclipse_cpp-2021-09_eclipse, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust, operand=, action=).
  ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine code=0 Error reading signed content.
  java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Arjan\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.oomph.preferences_1.12.0.v20200624-1156.jar (Het systeem kan het opgegeven bestand niet vinden)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.signedcontent.SignedContentFromBundleFile.lambda$2(SignedContentFromBundleFile.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.signedcontent.SignedContentFromBundleFile.getSignedEntries(SignedContentFromBundleFile.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.signedcontent.SignedContentFromBundleFile.<init>(SignedContentFromBundleFile.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.signedcontent.SignedBundleHook.getSignedContent(SignedBundleHook.java:170)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CertificateChecker.checkCertificates(CertificateChecker.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CertificateChecker.start(CertificateChecker.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust.completePhase(CheckTrust.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Phase.postPerform(Phase.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Phase.perform(Phase.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.PhaseSet.perform(PhaseSet.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Engine.perform(Engine.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Engine.perform(Engine.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.director.PlanExecutionHelper.executePlan(PlanExecutionHelper.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl$3.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:549)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2.impl.P2TaskImpl.perform(P2TaskImpl.java:904)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.doPerformNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3851)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3779)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performTriggeredSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3760)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.perform(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3638)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.installPerform(SimpleVariablePage.java:1343)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.access$33(SimpleVariablePage.java:1211)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage$20.run(SimpleVariablePage.java:1156)

[2021-11-18 20:37:38] 
[2021-11-18 20:38:31] Executing bootstrap tasks
[2021-11-18 20:38:31] OpenJDK Runtime Environment 16.0.2+7-67
[2021-11-18 20:38:31] Product org.eclipse.products.epp.package.cpp.2021-09
[2021-11-18 20:38:31] Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup 1.21.0.v20210808-1248, build=5169, branch=4f2d83d895798b31dc987dc9c07da7c94b536f1d
[2021-11-18 20:38:31] Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup.core 1.21.0.v20210828-0732, build=5169, branch=4f2d83d895798b31dc987dc9c07da7c94b536f1d
[2021-11-18 20:38:31] Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2 1.17.0.v20210601-0619, build=5169, branch=4f2d83d895798b31dc987dc9c07da7c94b536f1d
[2021-11-18 20:38:31] Performing P2 Director (Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers (2021-09))
[2021-11-18 20:38:31] Offline = false
[2021-11-18 20:38:31] Mirrors = true
[2021-11-18 20:38:31] Resolving 34 requirements from 3 repositoriesto C:\Users\Arjan\eclipse\cpp-2021-09\eclipse
[2021-11-18 20:38:31] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:epp.package.cpp [4.21.0,5.0.0) (filter=(|(&(osgi.arch=aarch64)(osgi.os=linux)(osgi.ws=gtk))(&(osgi.arch=x86_64)(osgi.os=linux)(osgi.ws=gtk))(&(osgi.arch=x86_64)(osgi.os=macosx)(osgi.ws=cocoa))(&(osgi.arch=x86_64)(osgi.os=win32)(osgi.ws=win32))))
[2021-11-18 20:38:31] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [4.21.0,5.0.0)
[2021-11-18 20:38:31] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group [4.21.0,5.0.0)
[2021-11-18 20:38:31] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.cdt.autotools.feature.group
[2021-11-18 20:38:31] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.cdt.build.crossgcc.feature.group
[2021-11-18 20:38:31] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.cdt.cmake.feature.group
[2021-11-18 20:38:31] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.cdt.debug.gdbjtag.feature.group
[2021-11-18 20:38:31] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.cdt.debug.standalone.feature.group
[2021-11-18 20:38:31] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.cdt.debug.ui.memory.feature.group
[2021-11-18 20:38:31] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.cdt.docker.launcher.feature.group
[2021-11-18 20:38:31] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.cdt.feature.group
[2021-11-18 20:38:31] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.cdt.launch.remote.feature.group
[2021-11-18 20:38:31] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.cdt.launch.serial.feature.feature.group
[2021-11-18 20:38:31] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.cdt.meson.feature.group
[2021-11-18 20:38:31] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.cdt.testsrunner.feature.feature.group
[2021-11-18 20:38:31] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.egit.feature.group
[2021-11-18 20:38:31] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.epp.mpc.feature.group
[2021-11-18 20:38:31] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.launchbar.feature.group
[2021-11-18 20:38:31] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.launchbar.remote.feature.group
[2021-11-18 20:38:31] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.linuxtools.cdt.libhover.devhelp.feature.feature.group
[2021-11-18 20:38:31] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.linuxtools.cdt.libhover.feature.feature.group
[2021-11-18 20:38:31] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.linuxtools.changelog.c.feature.group
[2021-11-18 20:38:31] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.linuxtools.gcov.feature.group
[2021-11-18 20:38:31] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.linuxtools.gprof.feature.feature.group
[2021-11-18 20:38:31] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.linuxtools.rpm.feature.group
[2021-11-18 20:38:31] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.linuxtools.valgrind.feature.group
[2021-11-18 20:38:31] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext_feature.feature.group
[2021-11-18 20:38:31] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.tm.terminal.connector.cdtserial.feature.feature.group
[2021-11-18 20:38:31] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.tm.terminal.feature.feature.group
[2021-11-18 20:38:31] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.tracecompass.gdbtrace.feature.group
[2021-11-18 20:38:31] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.tracecompass.lttng2.control.feature.group
[2021-11-18 20:38:31] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.tracecompass.lttng2.kernel.feature.group
[2021-11-18 20:38:31] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.tracecompass.lttng2.ust.feature.group
[2021-11-18 20:38:31] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.oomph.setup.feature.group
[2021-11-18 20:38:31] Repository https://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/2021-09/202109101200
[2021-11-18 20:38:31] Repository https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2021-09/202109151000
[2021-11-18 20:38:31] Repository http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
[2021-11-18 20:38:33] Calculating requirements and dependencies.
[2021-11-18 20:38:33] Computing prerequisite plan
[2021-11-18 20:38:36] Collecting 4 artifacts from https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2021-09/202109151000
[2021-11-18 20:38:36] Downloading org.eclipse.platform_root
[2021-11-18 20:38:36] Downloading org.eclipse.rcp_root
[2021-11-18 20:38:36] Downloading org.eclipse.platform.ide.executable.win32.win32.x86_64
[2021-11-18 20:38:36] Downloading org.eclipse.cdt_root
[2021-11-18 20:38:36] Collected 4 artifacts for https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2021-09/202109151000 in 0.558s
[2021-11-18 20:38:36] Collecting 1 artifacts from https://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/2021-09/202109101200
[2021-11-18 20:38:36] Downloading epp.package.cpp.executable.win32.win32.x86_64
[2021-11-18 20:38:36] Collected 1 artifacts for https://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/2021-09/202109101200 in 0s
[2021-11-18 20:38:36] An error was detected while performing the engine operation and the changes are being rolled back. See the log for details.
[2021-11-18 20:38:36] ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine code=4 An error occurred during the org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust phase.
  at org.eclipse.oomph.util.OomphPlugin.coreException(OomphPlugin.java:291)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl$3.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:553)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:345)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2.impl.P2TaskImpl.perform(P2TaskImpl.java:904)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.doPerformNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3851)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3779)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performTriggeredSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3760)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.perform(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3638)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.installPerform(SimpleVariablePage.java:1343)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.access$33(SimpleVariablePage.java:1211)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage$20.run(SimpleVariablePage.java:1156)
  ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine code=0 session context was:(profile=C__Users_Arjan_eclipse_cpp-2021-09_eclipse, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust, operand=, action=).
  ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine code=0 Error reading signed content.
  java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Arjan\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.oomph.preferences_1.12.0.v20200624-1156.jar (Het systeem kan het opgegeven bestand niet vinden)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.signedcontent.SignedContentFromBundleFile.lambda$2(SignedContentFromBundleFile.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.signedcontent.SignedContentFromBundleFile.getSignedEntries(SignedContentFromBundleFile.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.signedcontent.SignedContentFromBundleFile.<init>(SignedContentFromBundleFile.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.signedcontent.SignedBundleHook.getSignedContent(SignedBundleHook.java:170)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CertificateChecker.checkCertificates(CertificateChecker.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CertificateChecker.start(CertificateChecker.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust.completePhase(CheckTrust.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Phase.postPerform(Phase.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Phase.perform(Phase.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.PhaseSet.perform(PhaseSet.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Engine.perform(Engine.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Engine.perform(Engine.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.director.PlanExecutionHelper.executePlan(PlanExecutionHelper.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl$3.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:549)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2.impl.P2TaskImpl.perform(P2TaskImpl.java:904)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.doPerformNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3851)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3779)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performTriggeredSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3760)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.perform(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3638)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.installPerform(SimpleVariablePage.java:1343)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.access$33(SimpleVariablePage.java:1211)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage$20.run(SimpleVariablePage.java:1156)

[2021-11-18 20:38:36]
```

I could not uninstall Eclipse IDE, so I deleted all Eclipse related files from my PC. Now I cannot re-install the program anymore. I keep getting this weird error. I have no idea what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the Eclipse directory is actually the only way to [uninstall Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50855742/897024), so you didn't do anything wrong.

To me it looks like some bundle is missing or corrupted. It might help to delete the `.p2` directory in your User directory and then try to install it again.