# How to cleanly uninstall an Eclipse Installation using Oomph and/or P2?

Tags: oomph

I have used the Eclipse Installer and created a number of Installations on disk. These installations share a bundle pool.

I would like to correctly uninstall some of these installations, removing the installation and its dependencies only and leaving the bundle pool intact.

Q: What is the best practice to cleanly removing an Oomph Installer provided installation, including startup link and dangling bundle pool references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The installer doesn't support uninstalling and everything has to be removed manually. As far as I know there isn't even any official documentation about uninstalling but I gathered a lot information about where files related to Eclipse can be located in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50855742/897024

The bundle pool seems to be the only part that is somewhat automated in this regard. Once you have manually deleted an Eclipse installation folder, you can run the "Cleanup Agent" which you find in the "Bundle Pool Management" dialog of the Eclipse installer. It should be able to detect and remove any unused bundles but keeps bundles used by other Eclipse installations.